# Utility.SearchPrincipals does not return any results

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am writing a provider hosted SharePoint 2013 application. I'm using SharePoint online.

Since the people picker isn't supported in this scenario, I need to build my own. I found the [SearchPrincipals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.utilities.utility.searchprincipals.aspx) method. That seems like exactly what I'm looking for, but no matter what I try, the method is returning with 0 results.

What little information I've found around this method suggests that the problem is usually a permissions issue, but the user that I'm logged in as is a Site Collection Administrator (`ClientContext.Web.CurrentUser.IsSiteAdmin` is `true`), so that shouldn't be the case with me.

I've tried passing in virtually every combination of `PrincipalType` and `PrincipalSource`, even ones that didn't make sense. I've also tried passing in `ClientContext.Web.SiteUsers` for the scope, and also `null`, both of which I've seen used in my searches, and that didn't turn up any results either.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The `ClientContext` of the CSOM (Client Side Object Model) allows the developer to make multiple --unrelated -- queries. It queues up these queries and does not execute them until `ExecuteQuery` is called. Even though `SearchPrincipals` is a static method off of the `Utility` class, it still translates the method call into a query and queues it up. The method will **always** return an empty collection, but once you call `ExecuteQuery` on the `ClientContext`, that collection is then filled with the results of the search.

Also, another problem that I ran into immediately afterwards was that I was getting an error that seemed completely unrelated to my query when I called `ExecuteQuery`. It turns out that there was code that previously executed that queued up some queries, but it never executed them, so when I called `ExecuteQuery`, it executed those queries as well, and one of those was erroring. If you are getting an unexpected error, it's a good idea to see if there are other queued queries that haven't been executed yet. You can check the boolean property `HasPendingRequest` to help determine this.

Hopefully this answer saves other people a lot of time!